# External factors influencing running performance

Tags: running, performance

I plan to create a training plan for myself for different running events by aligning with external factors, specific to every event, which contribute to running performance. Is there any reference for understanding those?
Thanks.

Comment: "External factors" seems like a ridiculously broad term. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: I was looking into factors like temp, humidity, wind, elevation etc and how they relate to a reference in numbers. For example strava shows a CAG for every split. Though strava takes into consideration the elevation factor it does not care for the other factors and their relationships that I mentioned here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also think this is too broad to really answer, in addition, many of the factors that you mention will vary from person to person in how they react to them. Your best bet is to keep a training journal and track how *you* react to the changes, and adjust accordingly.